# Why the use of "conio.h" is not good habit of programming?

Tags: c

I have attended many online coding competition, they usually mention the note that `#include<conio.h>` means `conio.h` header can not be used.
**I am not aware about all functions included by this header but curios to know that why it's not a good programming habit?**
If anybody can explains some of it's functions should not be used.

> example clrscr().

Comment: Obsolete in addition to being platform-specific and nonstandard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21329589/7508077

Answer (score 7):

Well, `conio.h` is platform-specific. If you try to compile on Linux, your code will probably not compile. Also - using functions to manipulate the console window make your program less reusable than if you were using just standard input and output (you cannot redirect the stdin/stdout so easily).

If you are making rich console applications, you can instead use cross-platform libraries, such as `ncurses`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not standard

> [...] it is not part of the C standard library, ISO C nor is it defined by POSIX. [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h)

Some compilers support it but they are platform depended  and it's hard to write a portable code between them.