# Why must we refrain from using conio.h? Is it obsolete?

Tags: c

I have started programming in C a few years ago. The two most commonly used header files were `<conio.h>` and `<stdio.h>`. All my favourite functions for clearing the screen `clrscr()` the infamous `getch()` function from stopping the window from terminating after it completes etc.

A few years later after I've attended a class regarding programming languages and practices, I've been asked to refrain from using the `conio.h` header file. Is using `conio` a bad practice in modern programming? What's the reason? why are people so anti-C against using the good old C libraries?

Comment: `<conio.h>` is non-standard and non-portable. Use a cross-platform library such as `ncurses` if you need functionality not provided by the standard C libraries.

Comment: I think it's only widely supported on DOS and Windows console applications - you'd need to use different APIs (e.g. ncurses) on Linux etc.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h

Comment: @PaulR your comment should be an answer.

Comment: OK - converted to answer now...

Comment: @ecatmur Yeah, I've read that. My question here is `conio.h` being obsolete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<conio.h>` is non-standard and non-portable. Use a cross-platform library such as [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) if you need functionality not provided by the standard C libraries.

Comment: But is ncurses usable on windows? [GNU ncurses page](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) lists it in "Future Plans" section.

Comment: It certainly seems to be: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ncurses.htm

Comment: Can I use it on Visual Studio 2010? Does it support additional functions compared to `conio`?

Comment: Yes to both questions: it does a lot more than `conio`, e.g. text windows.