# error 'clreol' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm new to c++. I am having a trouble with creating a clreol(); (clear end of line) function in C++ language. And also I am using Code::Blocks.The header file you're trying to use is very old and outdated.
I'm trying to do like:
`

```
void LINES::CLEARDOWN(void)
{
 for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++)
 {
  sleep(20);
  gotoxy(1, i);
  clreol();
 }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me the alternate way to use clreol()

Comment: You need to include the header file with the declaration of the function ```clreol``` you want to use, so probably ```#include "conio.h"```, but see discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329485/why-must-we-refrain-from-using-conio-h-is-it-obsolete and in links therein.

Comment: Thanks for response but I'm already using `#include "conio.h` and I'm also using GNU GCC Compiler. Can you please elaborate what you want to say?

Answer (score 1):

You can replicate the functionality of `clreol()` using ANSI escape sequences. Note that this will *not* work on windows.

The escape sequence to clear a line from the right of the cursor is `Esc[K`, to write this to the terminal in C++ we can do this:

```cpp
std::cout << "\033[K";
```

(`\033` is ESC)

To move the cursor back one we can do

```cpp
std::cout << "\033[1D";
```

(Where 1 is the amount we are moving by and D specifies backwards aka left)

And so on and so forth. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) has a description of ANSI escape codes and how they are "constructed". If you want to do heavy manipulation of terminal graphics (i.e are writing a terminal GUI) then you should consider [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).